# Typoscript Lib object does not render images

Tags: image, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

In my TYPO3 I have a page with a content element as an Image.

I render the image using a lib object, like this:

```
lib.myObject = COA
lib.myObject.imageContent < styles.content.get
lib.myObject.imageContent.select.where = colPos = 1
lib.myObject.imageContent.select.pidInList = 99
lib.myObject.imageContent.stdWrap.wrap = |
```

This works fine if the content is TEXT/TEXT-IMAGE, but if its an IMAGE alone, the image does not render. Although, it shows the following comments.

```
<!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:123/image [begin] -->
<!--  Image block: [begin] -->
<!--  Image block: [end] -->
<!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:123/image [end] -->
```

Do I need to enable anything to render the images ? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a new TYPO3 6.1 installation. Just figured out, how to fix this. The reports (Backend -> Admin Tools -> Reports) showed a warning regarding my TYPO3 System. I had to run the Update Wizard in the Install Tool to complete the Update from 4.x to 6.1. Don't know why there was TYPO3 4.x running as I hat a new 6.1 installation but however that does the trick. Hope that might help you as well.